# HttpRequestMessage.CreateErrorResponse() Doesn't Exist

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I was just reading about [web API model validation](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/model-validation-in-aspnet-web-api) and it has this example, however the example code provided below won't compile because `CreateErrorResponse()` doesn't exist in `HttpRequestMessage`. Does anyone know why?

```
public class ValidateModelAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
    {
        public override void OnActionExecuting(HttpActionContext actionContext)
        {
            if (actionContext.ModelState.IsValid == false)
            {
                actionContext.Response = actionContext.Request.CreateErrorResponse(
                    HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, actionContext.ModelState);
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`CreateErrorResponse` is an extension method, add `using System.Net.Http;`

documentation: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httprequestmessageextensions.createerrorresponse(v=vs.118).aspx

Comment: @Augustin Seifert - How would you know that HttpRequestMessage has extension methods? It doesn't say anything about it on https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httprequestmessage(v=vs.118).aspx

Comment: navigate the assembly classes https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http(v=vs.118).aspx

Comment: ok thanks. But why would they not mention it on the HttpRequestMessage page?